# Ensuring that the Thread calling Socket.XXXAsync stays alive to complete the IO request (IO Completion Port, C#)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous

I am implementing a small library to make the use of `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` easier. It should handle an arbitrary number of listening and receiving TCP sockets and it is important that the implementation is ~fast~.

I am using the `XXXAsync` methods and the CLR `ThreadPool` to call back into the delegates of the library user  (for example, whenever a message was successfully sent or some data was received). Preferable the library wouldn't start any threads by itself.

The user of the library can access an interface to my `Sockets` wrapper to send message or to start receiving messages (among many other methods and overloads):

```
public interface IClientSocket {
    // will eventually call Socket.SendAsync
    IMessageHandle SendAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length);

    // will eventually call Socket.RecieveAsync
    void StartReceiveAsync();
}
```

The `XXXAsync` methods use IO Completion Ports. Thus, the thread which calls these methods must stay alive until the operation completes, otherwise the operation fails with `SocketError.OperationAborted` (I think that is the case, or no?).
Imposing such a restriction on the user of the library is ugly and error prone.

What is the best alternative here?

- Calling `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` with a delegate to invoke the `XXXAsync` methods? Is that safe? I read somewhere, that the ThreadPool won't stop idle threads which have any IOCP. That would be good as it solves the problem above.
  But it could also be bad with many TCP connections.
  In such a case is is likely that each ThreadPool thread invoked one of the pending `ReceiveAsync` calls. Therefore the ThreadPool would never shrink even if the current workload is low and many Threads are idle (and wasting memory).
- Starting a dedicated thread which is always alive and invokes the `XXXAsync` methods. For example, when a library user want to send data, it places a delegate into a syncronized queue, the thread pops it and invokes the `SendAsync` method.
  I don't like this solution much, because it wastes a thread and on a multi core machine, sending is only performed by one thread.

Moreover both solutions don't seam the best because they pass the job to call the asyncronous method to another thread. Can that be avoided?

What do you think? (Thank you!!)

Thomas

EDIT 1:

I can reproduce the `SocketError.OperationAborted` problem with the following test program (I think it is correct).
Compile, start and telnet to port 127.0.0.1:10000. Send a "t" or a "T" and wait for > 3 seconds. When sending "T", the `ReceiveAsync` call is done in the ThreadPool (works), with "t" a new thread is started which terminates after 3 seconds (fails).

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test {
    class Program {
        static List<Socket> _referenceToSockets = new List<Socket>();
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Main Thread";

            // Create a listening socket on Port 10000.
            Socket ServerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            _referenceToSockets.Add(ServerSocket);
            var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 10000);
            ServerSocket.Bind(endPoint);
            ServerSocket.Listen(50);

            // Start listening.
            var saeaAccept = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            saeaAccept.Completed += OnCompleted;
            ServerSocket.AcceptAsync(saeaAccept);

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Listening on {0}.", endPoint));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void OnCompleted(object obj, SocketAsyncEventArgs evt) {
            var socket = (Socket)obj;
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Async operation completed: {0}; Error: {1}; Callback-Thread: \"{2}\" ({3} threadpool)", evt.LastOperation, evt.SocketError, Thread.CurrentThread.Name, Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread?"is":"no"));
            switch (evt.LastOperation) {
                case SocketAsyncOperation.Accept:
                    // Client connected. Listen for more.
                    Socket clientSocket = evt.AcceptSocket;
                    _referenceToSockets.Add(clientSocket);
                    evt.AcceptSocket = null;
                    socket.AcceptAsync(evt);

                    // Start receiving data.
                    var saeaReceive = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
                    saeaReceive.Completed += OnCompleted;
                    saeaReceive.SetBuffer(new byte[1024], 0, 1024);
                    clientSocket.ReceiveAsync(saeaReceive);
                    break;
                case SocketAsyncOperation.Disconnect:
                    socket.Close();
                    evt.Dispose();
                    break;
                case SocketAsyncOperation.Receive:
                    if (evt.SocketError != SocketError.Success) {
                        socket.DisconnectAsync(evt);
                        return;
                    }
                    var asText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(evt.Buffer, evt.Offset, evt.BytesTransferred);
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Received: {0} bytes: \"{1}\"", evt.BytesTransferred, asText));
                    if (evt.BytesTransferred == 0) {
                        socket.Close();
                        evt.Dispose();
                    }
                    if (asText.ToUpper().StartsWith("T")) {
                        Action<object> action = (object o) => {
                            socket.ReceiveAsync(evt);
                            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Called ReceiveAsync {0}...", o));
                            Thread.Sleep(3000);
                            Console.WriteLine("End of Action...");
                        };
                        if (asText.StartsWith("T")) {
                            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o=>action(o), "in ThreadPool");
                        } else {
                            new Thread(o=>action(o)).Start("in a new Thread");
                        }
                    } else {
                        socket.ReceiveAsync(evt);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT #3

The following is the solution I intend to use:

I let the thread of the library user invoke the `XXXAsync` (except `SendAsync`) operations directly. In the most cases the call will be successfull (because the calling thread does terminate only seldomly).
If the operation failed with `SocketError.OperationAborted`, the library just invokes the operation again using the current thread from the async callback. This one is a `ThreadPool` thread and it has a good chance to succeed (an additional flag will be set, to use this workaround at most once if the reason for `SocketError.OperationAborted` was cause due to some other error).
This should work because the socket itself is still ok, just the previous operation failed.

For the `SendAsync`, this workaround does not work, because it could mess up the order of the messages. In this case I will queue the messages in a FIFO list. I will use the `ThreadPool` to dequeue them and send them via `SendAsync`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of red flags here.  If you've got trouble keeping the thread alive then you've got a thread that's not doing anything useful.  In which case it doesn't make sense to use Async methods.  If speed is your only concern then you should not use the Async methods.  They require that the Socket grabs a tp thread to make the callback.  That's small overhead but there is *none* if a regular thread makes a blocking call.

You should only consider the Async methods when you need to make your app scale well when you handle many simultaneous connections.  That produces very bursty cpu loads, perfect for tp threads.

Comment: It is not that I have any non useful threads running. It is rather that I don't want the library to enforce its user to make sure that its own thread stayed alive until all initiated operations complete. I guess, the only possiblity to garantee that, is to make the XXXAsync call from a thread under the libraries control **or** by using the ThreadPool. I wonder, does the CLR garantee that it won't end any CLR ThreadPool threads with outstanding IO operations,

Comment: If the library client doesn't want to stick around for the read result, isn't the exception exactly what you want?

Comment: Just because the library client lets the thread invoking SendAsync terminate, he still cares about the read result. He expects the result in an other thread (CRL `ThreadPool`), regardless what happens to the thread he used to call RecvAsync. Moreover the library gets a SocketError from the client, but the socket is still ok, just that particular operation failed (or is the socket closed then? Have to check...). In case of a receive its easy, just repeat it. For sending data its more complicated, because the application TCP protocol might not tolerate the loss of messages.

Comment: Well, you are making it simple then.  If you want to provide these guarantees then you'll have to spin up your own thread and use blocking calls.  Or you let the client choose by also offering both options, just like .NET did.

Comment: You are right. I will go that way. Except, that I won't use blocking calls (i would need by far too many threads :) ). With a thread under my control, the XXXAsync methods work fine. Thank you. See Edit #3.

Answer (score 0):

> the thread which calls these methods must stay alive until the operation completes"

I'm not convinced of the veractiy of this statement. When you start a network operation this is handed off to the Windows IO system. When a network event occurs (i.e. data is received and your app is notified) this can happily be dealt with by another thread (even if the initiating thread has long since died).

*Are you sure you're not dropping a reference to something crucial and allowing it to be garbage collected?*

If you are in a situation where threads are allowed to die then I would suspect that your code isn't ready to scale to the mega-fast/stellar # of clients. If you're really looking to scale, your use of threads should be very tightly controlled. The cost of letting a thread die (where I'm assuming another would need spinning up to replace it) isn't one that you should allow to happen too much. Thread pools are very definitely the way to go here.

Comment: Hi spender, I added my test code to reproduce the problem. I think the problem can be seen that way.  I agree with your second paragraph. One option would be a compile time flag to compile the library with the unsafe behavoir for high performance (after profiling that there is an actual bottleneck :-) ). I just wonder what's the best solution.